# How to fix CPU clock (for benchmarking purposes)?

Tags: cpu-speed

How to make the CPU not change the speed (clock)?

I want to compare execution time of some programs and need constant CPU performance (not necessarily *high* performance).

The CPU in question is i7-2640M, OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

(google finds only answers to how to repair ("fix") CPU speed or increase it, due to (my) english... is there a word that means "fix - make stable" and is used often?)

Answer (score 2):

From Power Management. First of all, you choose **High performance** plan.

[image]

Select **Change Advanced Power Settings** and make sure that the marked values are 100%.

[image]

There may also be a similar BIOS setting!

Comment: This, and disable Turbo Boost in BIOS.